# Setup a startpage without a correspondig menuitem in Joomla

Tags: joomla, menu

In Joomla 1.5 I would like to have a startpage (that has its own template) but there should be no corresponding menuitem "startpage". If the user wants to navigate to the startpage the only way he can do that is by clicking on the logo in the header. How can I achieve this in joomla? Currently it seems that I am forced to select a menuitem as the "default" menu item to define that this menuitem will be used as the starting point. But it also seems that I can not hide that particular menu item. Also I am not quite sure how to setup a common header that when clicking on it naviagtes to the startpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a menu that you do not display (perhaps `hiddenmenu` in addition to `mainmenu`), then place the default menu item there. You do not have to display every (or any) of the menus you create in Joomla. As for the logo, creating a link to '/' should work if your site is at the domain level.